# Date from spreadsheet and Today's Date in app script

Tags: date, google-apps-script

why this is not working?
Im trying to get the value Today into this input, but I can´t

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="fechaActual">Fecha Actual</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaActual" disabled>
      </div>
```

js

```
document.getElementById("searchtext").addEventListener("input",getasig);
document.getElementById("searchtext").addEventListener("input",fecha_actual);

 function fecha_actual(){
 var fecha = new Date();
 var month = fecha.getUTCMonth()+1;
 var day = fecha.getUTCDate();
 var year = fecha.getUTCFullYear();
 document.getElementById("fechaActual").value = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
   }
```

It doesn't shows anything...

I also have another input where I want to capture de date that is in my spreadsheet, but its only working if the columns is tag as Text...
Here is my gs code

```
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="Asignacion">Fecha de Asignación</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Asignacion" disabled>
      </div>



function getAsignacion (getasig){
  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url); 
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("MAR");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1, ws.getLastRow(),4).getValues();
  
  var dniList = data.map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var daytList = data.map(function(r){return r[1];});
  
  var position = dniList.indexOf(getasig);
  if(position > -1){
    return daytList[position];
  } else{
    return 'NO';
  }
  }
```

and this is my js script

```
  function getasig(){
  var dnicode = document.getElementById("searchtext").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateEsto).getAsignacion(dnicode);
  }
    function updateEsto(dia1){
   document.getElementById("Asignacion").value = dia1;  
  }
```

Here is an image of what I´m trying to do...

[THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfp44.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide the code related to element `searchtext`? It is an element that has an `input` event, right? Have you checked whether the function `fecha_actual` is running at all? Also, how is the rest of the code you provided related to your problem (for example, `Asignacion`? According to your question, there's HTML in your `.gs` file. I guess that's not the case?

Answer (score 0):

I found it difficult to follow your code so here's a simple search dialog that might help you.

GS:

```
function search(v) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let tf=sh.createTextFinder(v).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  let vA=[];
  tf.forEach(t =>{
    vA.push({row:t.getRow(),col:t.getColumn()});
  });
  return vA;
}

function launchADialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'),'Find a Number');
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
  <style> div #result{display:inline block;height:100px;width:100%}</style>
</head>

<body>
    
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter a number" id="txt"/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" />
   </form>
   <div id="result"></div>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',search,false);
     }
   function search() {
     console.log('search');
     let v = document.getElementById('txt').value;
     if(isNaN(v)) {
       document.getElementById('txt').focus();
       return;
     }
     if(v) {
       google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler((vA)=>{
         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=vA.map(obj=>{ return ['<br />row:' + obj.row + ' col:' + obj.col]}).join('');
       })
       .search(v);
     }
   }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Sheet1 Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 18 | 6 | 15 | 6 | 13 | 19 | 16 | 9 | 8 |
| 5 | 7 | 14 | 5 | 3 | 16 | 12 | 8 | 16 | 16 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | 14 | 5 | 6 | 18 | 18 | 7 | 19 |
| 7 | 10 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 8 | 14 | 14 | 15 | 15 |
| 10 | 13 | 15 | 9 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 18 | 14 | 10 |
| 4 | 9 | 14 | 5 | 12 | 17 | 2 | 8 | 9 | 4 |
| 14 | 16 | 11 | 8 | 4 | 13 | 17 | 11 | 18 | 6 |
| 12 | 14 | 17 | 9 | 14 | 18 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 18 |
| 18 | 17 | 5 | 3 | 18 | 17 | 18 | 15 | 16 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 | 13 | 5 | 1 | 19 | 10 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 11 | 16 | 1, 18 | 19 | 8 | 5 | 0 | 17 | 7 | 6 |
| 18 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 13 | 4 | 14 | 6 | 18 |
| 6 | 19 | 17 | 13 | 18 | 0 | 14 | 6 | 4 | 3 |
| 0 | 6 | 19 | 17 | 6 | 13 | 5 | 17 | 10 | 7 |
| 8 | 12 | 5 | 8 | 13 | 7 | 11 | 0 | 7 | 4 |
| 2 | 16 | 12 | 19 | 14 | 18 | 18 | 15 | 0 | 4 |
| 3 | 18 | 7 | 14 | 0 | 13 | 11 | 16 | 15 | 13 |
| 8 | 13 | 5 | 13 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 17 | 4 | 7 |
| 14 | 14 | 1 | 18 | 19 | 6 | 11 | 19 | 2 | 12 |
| 6 | 11 | 17 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 9 | 7 | 0 | 5 |

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I already have the search code... the problem is that I have 1 column with IDs and the second with Date... Its works but It doesn´t bring the information from the columns with date, except if this one is set as text...

Comment: I hope you realize that date object cannot be passed via [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)  you can however pass them as strings

Comment: Why do you the 'fetchActual' disabled?

Comment: There's not enough code in your question for me to completely understand what your trying to do.

Comment: I have the input disabled so users can´t  make changes in those inputs.. but I just changed to readonly